# How can I get back my lost data after refreshing Windows?

Tags: windows-8, windows-8-refresh

I refreshed my laptop, and now all my important pics have disappeared from a folder that used to be on the desktop.

How can I get them back?

Comment: Did you check `C:\Windows.old\Users`?

Answer (score 2):

There are a [couple of ways](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows-8/restore-refresh-reset-pc) that you could have refreshed Windows. How did you do it?

- If during the recovery, you selected *Refresh your PC without affecting your files*, then your files should have been saved in `C:\Windows.old`
- If you selected *Remove everything and reinstall Windows*, then your files were deleted. At best, you could try using [data-recovery software](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_data_recovery_software) to attempt to get at least some of them back (which may or may not work depending on numerous factors specific to your system and usage).